# how to make this gradient and shadow box

Tags: css, gradient, photoshop

How can I create this gradient and shadow box from the attached image?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your can generate yourself check these lnks:

### http://css3generator.com/

### http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: These two tools help a lot to make the shadow box and gradient box.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you need or not, but basically it create a box with gradien and shadow.

```
.box
{
    background: #EEEEEE; /* for non-css3 browsers */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FEFEFE', endColorstr='#EEEEEE'); /* for IE */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FEFEFE), to(#EEEEEE)); /* for webkit browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FEFEFE,  #EEEEEE); /* for firefox 3.6+ */  
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #BEBEBE; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #BEBEBE; /* Safari, Chrome */
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #BEBEBE; /* CSS3 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this js fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/w6nLA/3/